# several RPis sharing wifi internet by cable, with same hostname. Precedence lookup?

Tags: raspbian, avahi

I've a Lab with a wifi AP. Students connect their laptops to this AP. Each student has a RPi3 that shares wifi internet by cable. i.e each student laptop acts as a gateway with wlan0, the external internet interface and eth0 the internal LAN interface connected to the RPi3

Laptops are Ubuntu boxes and eth0 is shared to other computers using NetworkManager. eth0 IP is 10.42.0.1 and RPi3 eth IP is dynamically assigned (dnsmasq) usually in a range 10.42.0.13X

My question is: since all RPi3 have same mDNS name raspberrypi.local, and students will 'ssh pi@raspberrypi.local', is there any hostname lookup precedence in avahi that will always select the local RPi3, thus making it unnecessary to give unique hostnames to each student RPi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mDNS` uses multicast and multicast traffic is not usually routed. Unless there is a `raspberrypi.local` on the Wifi network, you students will only see their own `raspberrypi.local`.

Comment: "_mDNS uses multicast and multicast traffic is not usually routed._" Specifically, mDNS uses `224.0.0.251` which is a Link-Local multicast that is _not allowed_ to be routed or sent off the link on which it originates. (Yes, I know some people do that, but if you break the rules, you get what you deserve.)